# what's the model/data drift metric for time series forecasting?

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, forecasting, model-evaluation, concept-drift

Suppose that I have time series forecasting model, e.g. forecasting point of sales revenue in various economic scenarios represented by indicators such as inflation or interest rates. I build a model $\hat y_{t+h|I_t}=f(X_{t+h|I_t}|\hat\theta_\tau)$, where $X$ are set of scenario variables and $\theta$ - model weights/parameters that were estimated at time $\tau<t$, .i.e. some time ago relative to current time t; h - forecast steps ahead. I denote all that is known and observed at or before time t as $I_t$.

I can obtain fit statistics from estimation of $\theta$, and also can obtain forecast errors from past periods $y_{s+h}-\hat y_{s+h|I_{s<t}}$. I'm looking for a suitable metric that would help determine whether the model needs to be re-estimated or maybe even re-built due to the drift in data since the model was estimated.

I was thinking too obtain the one step ahead forecast errors $r_s=y_{s+1}-\hat y_{s+1|I_{s}}$ for periods $s\le \tau$ and $s>\tau$ and compare their distributions, e.f. compare means and variance assuming they are independent random value draws. I could run ANOVA or similar to determine whether they look similar.

Comment: Interesting question. I don't know whether ANOVA is really helpful here, because there is likely no sharp breakpoint with a "before" and "after" that you could use for grouping (it's called "drift" after all!), and also, we all know that dichotomania is a Bad Thing, right? It might make sense to actually consider forecast errors as a time series in themselves and start analyzing these, looking for breakpoints (they might exist!), or evidence of trend.

Comment: But I don't have a good answer... Usually I would recommend just refitting periodically, rather than worrying about this. Or, if resources are limited, ranking different time series forecasts in order of badness (e.g., using relative error measures), then investing resources in them in decreasing order - pretty much regardless of whether badness comes from model drift or anywhere else. Looking forward to answers!

Comment: @StephanKolassa, even we re-fit regularly, the question is still when to change the model?

Comment: Yes, that's the more general "invest resources in" part. We should critically assess whether our model works if it performs "badly" (which is why we should assess "badness" in some way), whether this is due to model drift or not.